# Python isnull() - using Lambda on a row

Tags: python, dataframe, lambda, row, isnull

I am trying to add a column to a dataframe - ad_clicks.

ad_clicks already has a column - ad_click_timestamp which has time values if a customer clicked on the website. If he/she did not, then the value in the cell is nan.

If I do this -

```
ad_clicks['is_click'] = ~ad_clicks.ad_click_timestamp.isnull()
```

it works.

If I do this -

```
ad_clicks['is_click'] = ad_clicks.apply(lambda row : ~row.ad_click_timestamp.isnull(), axis = 1)
```

it throws me an error as follows -

```
AttributeError: ("'str' object has no attribute 'isnull'", u'occurred at index 0')
```

As per my understanding - using apply without a specified column, the input to the lambda function becomes the row and by specifying the column to operate on - it selects that particular column for each row and performs the operation.

So, why does the same expression work without the lambda - when applied to the column but not to with lambda when applied to the cell.

What am I missing here? Thanks in advance for any explanation (or syntax correction that I may be missing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because in an `apply` call, `row.ad_click_timestamp` would give a single item, which is like `np.nan`. So you would have to try:

```
ad_clicks['is_click'] = ad_clicks.apply(lambda row : ~np.isnan(row.ad_click_timestamp), axis = 1)
```

Or:

```
ad_clicks['is_click'] = ad_clicks.apply(lambda row : ~(row.ad_click_timestamp != row.ad_click_timestamp), axis = 1)
```

Comment: I need at least 15points to upvote but my feedback has been recorded. Was a useful answer. Thank you. As I understand now - isnull() is used on the series object which is what I had with ad_clicks.ad_clicks_timestamp. However, for a single object(string) which is what I get with the lambda row function isna(object) is the right function. Correct?

Comment: @RikkiS Yeah, you should at least click the check mark, to accept my answer, 15 rep isn't required for that